# What happen if I install VirtualBox Guest Additions on a host?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu installed.

This morning I Installed VirtualBox and booted my Ubuntu drive in a VM. I then installed the guest additions in Ubuntu.

My question/curiosity is, what would happen if I boot the drive again *outside* of the VirtualBox VM, using a physical computer?

Will my Ubuntu work normally or is something going to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Virtualbox Guest Additions are is a set of drivers/kernel module that allow the guest OS to talk and take advantage of the features of the VM "hardware". If you boot the USB drive outside of the VM, the hardware is going to appear different so, aside from some configuration changes (usually display and network), it should work normally.

Comment: it worked as good as expected.

Comment: @chepe263: Congrats!

Comment: now i just need a bigger drive haha

Answer (score 0):

Well, it SHOULD work without any problem, in theory.

However, I just got bitten by this, although not using Ubuntu. We deployed a Windows 11 image which was originally created on a VirtualBox VM and the VBox Guest Additions passed on to the physical hardware installation.

VBoxMouse.sys somehow interfered with the usb dongle of a laser pointer/presenter (various models tested). Pulling the usb dognle caused an instant BSOD. Later we found out that plugging and unplugging a second mouse behaved exactly the same. Removing VBoxMouse.sys (vboxdrvinst.exe driver uninstall vboxmouse.inf) restored normal operation.

So, yeah, there CAN be some interference in some cases, so beware.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).